# how to get first two word from a sentence using php for loop

Tags: php

I am trying to get first two word from a sentence using php

```
$inp_val= "this is our country";
```

output will be : `this is`

// this input value has different string as Like: this, this is our, this name is mine

// i need to get only first two word or if anyone wrote only one word then i got same word but if any one wrote two or more word then it will collect only first two word..

I am trying with below code but it won't work properly..

```
$words = explode(' ', $inp_val);

$shop_name = "";

if (str_word_count($words) == 1) {
    $shop_name .= mb_substr($words[0], 0, 1);
 } else {
   for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
        $w = $words[$i];
        $shop_name .= mb_substr($w, 0, 1);
      }
  }
```

Comment: "_Warning: str_word_count() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given_"

Comment: `$words` is an array, `$words[0]` and `$words[1]` will hold your two first words

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: If you dont know what `explode()` does there is a [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) Or add a `print_r($words)` to find out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After exploding the input value by space (as you have done), you can use `array_slice` to extract the 2 first elements, then use the `implode` to concat the 2 elements as a string.

```php
$inp_val   = "this is our country";
$shop_name = implode(" ", array_slice(explode(' ', $inp_val), 0, 2));
echo $shop_name;
//OUTPUT: this is
```

*This method that uses `array_slice` work well for one or more words*